# bootstrap navigation bar.link items align side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap navigation bar like this

[image]

For some reason the links are not aligned side by side. One is on top of each other..Please suggest. It is something very simple..If someone can suggest I would appreciate it. I am not a web developer..
[image]

```
<title></title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" name="viewport" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: If you want collapse navbar than you've to add navbar-header. https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar_collapse

Comment: You can use [react-bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction).

For navBar, You can follow along with [this](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) documentation.